# Sparklyr stack overflow error unioning multiple tables

Tags: r, sparklyr

I have a use case where I'd like to pull many tables into spark (as they're separate Cassandra partitions), and union them together such that I can work on the resulting large table using `dplyr` and `group_by`.

I can't work on all the tables completely independently as, say my separate tables are

```
(a1), (a2), (a3), (a4), (b1), (b2), (b3), (b4)
```

I need to submit a query to the tables

```
((a1, a2, a3, a4), (b1, b2, b3, b4))
```

hence I will need to do some grouping at least.  It is conceptually much easier then, to union everything and group by the "letter" in the above.

A MWE of the code I'm using that produces the stack overflow error is below:

```
# Removing this option results in an evaluation nested too deeply error
options( expressions = 5e5 )

library(sparklyr)
library(dplyr)
sc <- spark_connect(master = "local", spark_home = spark_home_dir())

n = 500

l = as.list(1:n)

for (i in 1:n) {
  l[[i]] <- copy_to(
    dest = sc, 
    iris, 
    name = paste0("iris", i), 
    overwrite = TRUE, 
    cache = TRUE)
}

dt = l %>% purrr::reduce(dplyr::union_all)
dt
```

Can anyone help me with a better way to do this? I understand the problem is that I'm submitting 500 union strings to the SQL builder so that there's is a ridiculous amount of function nesting going on, but not sure if there's an easier way, other than refactoring a lot of code.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was solved via a `sparklyr` bug report [here](https://github.com/rstudio/sparklyr/issues/764)